# MSSQL - Como calcular o tempo em que um registo esteve num determinado Estado através de uma tabela de logs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou a tentar fazer um query compatível com o SQL2008R2 para determinar o tempo em que um registo se manteve num determinado estado através de uma tabela de logs.

| RowId | IdEstadoInicial | IdEstadoFinal | IdRegisto | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 521 | NULL | 7 | 105 | 2022-12-14 09:23:34.030 |
| 522 | 7 | 2 | 105 | 2022-12-14 09:23:47.277 |
| 523 | 2 | 3 | 105 | 2022-12-14 09:26:27.083 |
| 529 | 3 | 2 | 105 | 2022-12-14 12:08:08.647 |
| 530 | 2 | 3 | 105 | 2022-12-14 15:13:46.980 |
| 531 | 3 | 2 | 105 | 2022-12-14 15:18:28.723 |

Estava a tentar fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
        SELECT
            log1.IdRegisto AS IdRegisto,
            log1.IdEstadoFinal AS IdEstado, 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, log1.DateCreated, ISNULL(log2.DateCreated, GETDATE()))) AS Tempo,
            MIN(log1.DateCreated) AS PrimeiraGravacao
        FROM
            TblLogsEstado log1 LEFT JOIN
            TblLogsEstado log2 
                ON log1.IdEstadoFinal = log2.IdEstadoInicial AND log1.IdRegisto = log2.IdRegisto AND log1.RowId < log2.RowId
        WHERE log1.IdRegisto = 105
        GROUP BY 
            log1.IdRegisto, log1.IdEstadoFinal
```

O problema é que está-me a calcular mal os tempos:

| IdRegisto | IdEstado | Tempo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | 2 | 96805 |
| 105 | 3 | 31104 |
| 105 | 7 | 13 |

Para o IdEstado 7 o resultado está correcto, para o IdEstado 3 o resultado correcto seria 9983 segundos e para o IdEstado 2 o resultado correcto seria +/- 77500 segundos (aqui o valor depende da hora em que a query é executada).

Esqueci-me de referir uma coisa importante na pergunta, a query tem de ser compatível com o SQL2008R2.

Comment: Tentou com "analytics" LAG LEAD , daria para fazer este calculo por linha, depois se poderia tirar somas ou médias.

Comment: Esqueci-me de referir uma coisa importante na pergunta, a query tem de ser compatível com o SQL2008R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
        SELECT
            log1.IdRegisto AS IdRegisto,
            log1.IdEstadoFinal AS IdEstado, 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, log1.DateCreated, ISNULL(log2.DateCreated, GETDATE()))) AS Tempo,
            MIN(log1.DateCreated) AS PrimeiraGravacao
        FROM
            TblIncidentesLogEstado log1 LEFT JOIN
            TblIncidentesLogEstado log2 
                ON log2.RowId = (
                    SELECT TOP 1
                        log3.RowId
                    FROM 
                        TblIncidentesLogEstado log3
                    WHERE
                        log1.IdEstadoFinal = log3.IdEstadoInicial AND log1.IdRegisto = log3.IdRegisto AND log1.RowId < log3.RowId
                )
        GROUP BY 
            log1.IdRegisto, log1.IdEstadoFinal
```